# Windows App Certification Kit doesn't generate results

Tags: windows-store-apps, app-certification-kit

I'm trying to get a store app certified, but after I've run the App Certification Kit, I can't access the results.
The certification process runs to the end, but the link to see the results points to a non-existent file (AppData/Local/Microsoft/AppCertKit/ValidationResult.htm)

I've tried reinstalling the Certification Kit, but no change.

My setup is: Visual Studio 2015 Community, App certification Kit 10.0 running under Windows 10 Pro

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Frauke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer from the MSDN forums, so I thought I'd share it here for anybody who has the same problem.

The workaround is to create an app package in VS, then launch the App Certification Kit ***from the start menu instead from inside VS!*** Running the ACK independently gives you the option to save the results as an XML file.

Why this option is not available when launching from VS must remain one of the great mysteries of our time, I suspect.